# Compare strings

Tags: solidity, string

I want to compare two strings but, by using:

```
             require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_car))==keccak256(abi.encodePacked(car)));
```

I get the following error:

```
InternalCompilerError: Unknown dynamically sized type: struct RentalCompleting.CarGroup memory
```

This is probably due to the fact that the variable _car is an argument given by the user. Does anyone know how can i do this, check the string given by the user to see if is the same has another string.

Comment: oh and how can i pass string type between contracts. man strings in solidity are annoying. note i'm using pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2

Comment: What are the types of `car` and `_car`? Are they strings or structs? In the case where both are string the code compiles without issues. You should include a minimal example that we can compile and test. Strings is one of the basic types, it has some limitations like you have to convert to bytes to do anything useful and its usage cost is higher that other basic types but it is used a lot without problems.